# How to sort multiple tables in Shiny

Tags: r, sorting, shiny, datatable, dt

Is there any way to sort a column in a table and the same column in another table? For example, in the code below I draw two datatables with mtcars data and I would like to sort the column mpg of the first table by clicking, showing the same sorting in the second table automatically, the same if I click on the second table, automatically sorting the first table.

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)

ui <- basicPage(
  h2("The mtcars data"),
  dataTableOutput("mytable"),
  br(),
  dataTableOutput("mytable2")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({
    mtcars
  })
  output$mytable2 = DT::renderDataTable({
    mtcars
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried using `stateSave` option with `datatable` and believe this might be helpful. The `order` option can be saved in `reactiveValues` and be updated when the order of either table changes. Before changing the `reactiveValues`, I make sure it is a change in order from what is stored, otherwise you may have duplicate updates of the `datatable`. Finally, because the state would be saved in localStorage, adding `stateDuration = -1` will prevent additional ordering when the user accesses the app again.

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  rv <- reactiveValues(
    options = list(stateSave = TRUE,
                   stateDuration = -1,
                   order = list())
  )
  
  output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(mtcars, options = rv$options)
  })
  
  output$mytable2 = DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(mtcars, options = rv$options)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$mytable_state$order, {
    if (!identical(rv$options$order, input$mytable_state$order)) {
      rv$options$order <- input$mytable_state$order
    }
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$mytable2_state$order, {
    if (!identical(rv$options$order, input$mytable2_state$order)) {
      rv$options$order <- input$mytable2_state$order
    }
  })
  
}
```

**Edit**: With regards to adding additional options, you would have different ways you could go about this.

First, you could add more options to `rv` (e.g., add `pageLength`):

```
rv <- reactiveValues(
    options = list(stateSave = TRUE,
                   stateDuration = -1,
                   pageLength = 5,
                   order = list())
)
```

Alternatively, if you want to add the `options` inside of `datatable`, and maybe use different options between the two tables, you could instead store the `order` in `rv`:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  rv <- reactiveValues(
    order = list()
  )
  
  output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(mtcars, options = list(
      stateSave = TRUE,
      stateDuration = -1,
      order = rv$order))
  })
  
  output$mytable2 = DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(mtcars, options = list(
      stateSave = TRUE,
      stateDuration = -1,
      order = rv$order))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$mytable_state$order, {
    if (!identical(rv$order, input$mytable_state$order)) {
      rv$order <- input$mytable_state$order
    }
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$mytable2_state$order, {
    if (!identical(rv$order, input$mytable2_state$order)) {
      rv$order <- input$mytable2_state$order
    }
  })
  
}
```

In this case, `rv$order` will store the table order only, and not all of the options.

Comment: It works, thanks! If I want to include more options inside the renderDataTable what should I do?

Comment: @JoseLuis Great - glad to hear. See my edited answer that describes two ways to approach this.